# ERROR 1064 In VIEW code

Tags: mysql, view

So ive been trying to figure this out for awhile. I keep getting "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MYSQL server version for the right syntax to use near `Details` ON Order.OrderID = `Order Details`.OrderID LEFT JOIN Products O` at line 8"
All my attempts to find the error have left me clueless. Ive been rereading my book just to see if im missing something but i cant find anything. So any help/explanation is greatly appreciated.

Here is my sql code so far.

```
CREATE VIEW ORDERS AS

SELECT
    Orders.OrderID,
    Orders.OrderDate,
   `Order Details`.ProductID,
   `Order Details`.UnitPrice,
   `Order Details`.Quantity,
   `Order Details`.Quantity * `Order Details.UnitPrice as Total,
   Products.ProductName,
   Customers.CompanyName

FROM Orders

    LEFT JOIN Employees ON Employees.EmployeeID = Orders.EmployeeID

    LEFT JOIN Customers ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID

    LEFT JOIN `Order Details` ON Orders.OrderID = `Order Details`.OrderID

    LEFT JOIN Products ON Products.ProductID = `Order Details`.ProductID;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your backticks are not balanced (as you can see by the shading in your question).  First, I would encourage you to avoid naming tables and columns in such a way that they names need escaping (i.e. avoid reserved words and use only alphanumeric characters and underscores).

In addition, your view name needs to be different from table names.

Your query is easier to write and to read using table aliases:

```
CREATE VIEW OrdersWithProducts AS
    SELECT o.OrderID, o.OrderDate,
           od.ProductID, od.UnitPrice, od.Quantity,
           (od.Quantity * od.UnitPrice) as Total,
           p.ProductName, c.CompanyName
    FROM Orders o LEFT JOIN
         Employees e
         ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID LEFT JOIN
         Customers c
         ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID LEFT JOIN
         `Order Details` od
         ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID LEFT JOIN
         Products p
         ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID;
```

Comment: Sorry the naming conventions cant be changed as it is a school practice server so i had no say in the names. I will however remember that when i do make my own server. Also i cant believe i missed that one little backtick. That seemed to have fixed the problem. Thank you!